# I want to export Oracle SQL query results - every column in a separate sheet?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, export

Let's assume we have

```
 select a, b, c 
 from table
```

I want to export column a into sheet 1, column b into sheet2 and column c into sheet 3 in one XML or Excel file

Comment: Show of your current efforts !

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more context here.  Is this part of a bigger program or something you're just dumping from sql*plus/sql developer?

If you can wrap this into a scripting language (python, powershell, etc) you have some convenient options inside the language.

If you're in sql*plus, you still have options depending on how much coding and reusability you are looking for.

It really depends on the context of what you're doing.

Comment: Yes its from sqlplus its a jobe in crontab that open sqlplus and run a qury the result for query export as csv and move to another server

Comment: I have a few thoughts on how you could do this.  The simplest to implement would be to break the sql into a series of spool and select statements.  For example:
`spool a.csv
select a from table;
spool b.csv
select b from table;`

However, there are a lot more options if you move to a PL/SQL implementation using the utl_file package for output.